# Create and set the same structure and vales Cookie as the one created by FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, setcookie

I have an application ASP.NET Core 2.1 and I want to create a cookie like a cookie created by FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie of ASP.NET MVC 4.5. Is It possible?

In the MVC I have this:

```
// some data put into Session like this, Session("FirstName") = objUser.FirstName
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(objUser.UserName, False)
```

Comment: Do you plan to store sensitive data inside cookie?

Comment: I don't know what really FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie does. What kind of data does it put inside the cookie?

Comment: Are you trying to implement custom authentication without ASP.NET Identity? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I have two sites, one in ASP.NET MVC 4.5 and a second on in ASP.NET CORE 2.1. The first one have security implemented by : <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120"/>
    </authentication>

Comment: With the second one, I'm trying to do the same logic that the first one has, to login. I mean that I go to the database with username and password and check if the user exists and the password is correct, after that I do the same things in the first one, putting into SESSION some data about the user but I don't know how to put the cookie that the first one put using FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie because I don't have this approach in core. I don't use anymore the login page from the first one to login, I want to use the second one to login into the first one.

Comment: You cannot use `FormAuthentication` in ASP.NET Core. Are you planning to authenticate new ASP.NET Core app with an existing database that ASP.NET MVC app is currently using? Or are you trying to implement `Single Sign-On`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't strictly possible. Even if you could get the two cookies to *look* the same, they'd be encrypted differently, such that one site wouldn't be able to read the cookie set by another.

That said, the ability does technically exist to share cookies between ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET MVC. However, it requires the ASP.NET MVC project to switch to using the Data Protection API, versus the old-school machineKey encryption. The ASP.NET Core docs have [more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Even with that, though, it's not going to work with FormsAuth (which uses ASP.NET Membership). You'd need to also update your MVC project to utilize ASP.NET Identity. Again, consult the documentation.